# Is there a generic way to convert a paginated entity to paginated DTO

Tags: java, mapstruct

I might be missing something, but thought there would be generic way to convert a Pagination with Entity list to Pagination of DTO list.

Is there one?

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, imports = {LocalDateTime.class, UUID.class})
public interface SomeMapper {
      SomeDto toDto(SomeEntity entity);
```

Going to try doing a default method and writing some code to do that.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, imports = {LocalDateTime.class, UUID.class})
public interface SomeMapper {
      SomeDto toDto(SomeEntity entity);

      default Page<SomeDto> toDto(Page<SomeEntity> page) {
         // Loop though page.dto
         // convert each one using toDto
         // add to Dto list
         // return to new Pageination with dto list and pagination parts set from page
      }
}
```

Update might be able to use something like:

```
  default Page<SomeDto> toDto(Page<SomeEntity> page) {
        final Page<SomeDto> pageDto = page.map(this::toDto);
        return pageDto;
    }
```

Comment: You can use the MapperFacade module for this. Then just loop through the Page object and convert all your entities using the facade. https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html

Comment: Thanks, but prefer to not use non-standard main libraries.  I thnk the update approach in main question may work.  Probably get a comment here there is a way without implementing code and hope to hear that and how.

Comment: That library works wonders because it removes all the boilerplate code of mapping each and every field across all your entities/DTOs. I don't know why you wouldn't want to take advantage of this. But it's up to you

Comment: @AlgorithmFromHell so does mapstruct, they''re two libraries fulfilling the same need in different ways

Comment: @Deltharis ok, I didn't know this was a thing, ok then. Actually good to know. Last I was working with mappings like this (~3 years ago) I don't think this tool was on the market

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.  Still a shame have to do implementation code as for me its standard Spring thing to return objects wrapped in Page.

Solution I added to the original post works as map does the following:

```
@Override
    public <U> Page<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> converter) {
        return new PageImpl<>(getConvertedContent(converter), getPageable(), total);
    }
```

So code I have is:

```
import org.mapstruct.*;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, imports = {LocalDateTime.class, UUID.class})
public interface SomeMapper {

    SomeDto toDto(SomeEntity entity);

    default Page<SomeDto> toDto(Page<SomeEntity> pageEntity) {
        final Page<SomeDto> pageDto = pageEntity.map(this::toDto);
        return pageDto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapstruct handles standard collections, so you can add methods that map dtoList to entityList and other way and trust autogeneration. What needs manual handling is just the Page part:

```
//mapstruct annotations
public interface SomeMapper {

    SomeDto toDto(SomeEntity entity);

    List<SomeDto> entitiesToDtos(List<SomeEntity> entity);

    default Page<SomeDto> pageEntityToPageDto(Page<SomeEntity> page) {
        List<SomeDto> dtoList = entitiesToDtos(page.getContent());
        return new PageImpl(dtoList, page.getPageable(), page.getTotalElements());
    }
}
```